# "error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git" when trying to switch to master branch

Tags: linux, git

I'm getting the following error message when trying to switch to the master branch.

```
[root@testlab testing_repo]# git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

[image]

Here are the steps I followed:

1. I created a master branch with name "testing_repo"
   and converted this directory to repository with `git init testing_repo`.
2. I created 3 files using `touch file1 file2 file3`
   in testing_repo.

   ```
   [root@testlab testing_repo]# ls
   file1  file2  file3
   ```

   these 3 files I have staged.
3. I created a new branch with `git checkout -b feat/add_git_tutorial`.
4. I added a new file `git_tut.txt` which i
   staged and commited using `git add` and `git commit -m "message"`.

   ```
   [root@testlab testing_repo]# ls
   file1  file2  file3  git_tut.txt
   ```
5. I tried to switch to master branch using `git checkout master`
   but I get an error:

   ```
   [root@testlab testing_repo]# git checkout master
   error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
   ```

Comment: Your questioh is currently unreadable the way it is formatted. Also, don't post images of text, enter the text as text into your question. Remember, you can't ask people to give you their time if you aren't willing to spend the time to make your question readable and sufficiently detailed.

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/help/formatting](/help/formatting) and also [/editing-help](/editing-help) for help on how to do so.

Comment: There is still some information missing and you need to reformat the question. But try running `git branch -l`I assume that it might be the case that there is no master branch but a main branch, if so you can just `git checkout main`.

Comment: "PFA Snapshot" ?

Answer (score 1):

### You do not have a branch named "master"

The error

```
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

is exactly the error you get if you try to check out a commit reference that does not exist, be it a branch name, tag name or commit hash. The wording of the message is misleading to people not familiar with the inner workings of git.

To see the list of branches in your repo:

```
git branch
```

I'll bet you won't see "master" in the output. There are two possibilities for why you don't have a "master" branch.

### Possibility #1: You switched branches before your first commit.

The default branch (usually "master" or "main", see next section) isn't created when you init the repo, but when you make your initial commit.  If you switch branches before that initial commit, the default branch ("master") is never created.

In your step 2 you created and staged some files. But then in your step 3 you switched branches before every committing those staged changes. So the default branch (e.g. "master") was not created. If you redo your above steps, but do a `git commit` before step 3, you should get a message that that files were committed to "master" (assuming that's your default branch, see below).

### Possibility #2: Your git is configured to use another default branch name for new repos.

It is possible your git installation is configured to initialize new repos with "main" or some other name instead of "master".

> ℹ️ If you want to understand the background behind switching from "master" to "main", read [Regarding Git and Branch Naming](https://sfconservancy.org/news/2020/jun/23/gitbranchname/)/

You can check what your installation's "default default" branch with:

```
git var GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

If you want to change the "default default" branch name for new repos, the easiest way is with:

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch <your_name_pref_here>
```

If you want to rename the default branch of an existing repo, say from "main" to "master":

```
git branch -m main master
```

Comment: Shubham it would be nice if you provide feedback as to whether this solved your problem, as I spent a bit of time on it.